# При проматывании страницы вниз aside заканчивается, и идет задний фон

Tags: html, css

[image: aside заканчивается]

У меня есть страница с новостями и когда новости не вмещаются на странице, они идут вниз и получается чтобы их посмотреть нужно проскроллить страницу. Но когда я начинаю это делать aside заканчивается и идет задний фон. Как решить это?

```css
body {
    background: #2c2c2c;
}

aside {
    float: left;
    background: #181818;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #4d4d4d;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

aside img {
    float: left;
    width: 57px;
}

aside .logo {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
}

aside h3 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

aside ul {
    list-style: none;
}

aside ul li {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: transform .4s ease;
}

aside ul li:hover, aside ul a:hover {
    color: #ff052f;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

aside ul li, aside ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

main .features {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
}

main .features h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

main .features p {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.alert-danger {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px 31.5%;
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-info {
    background: #ff052f;
    border: #ff052f;
    color: #fff;
}

form {
    margin-left: 26%;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.pr {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <aside>
        <img src="{% static 'main/img/logo.png' %}">
        <span class="logo">DoubleNut</span><br><br>
        <h3>Навигация</h3>
        <ul>
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney"></i> Главная</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'about' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i> О нас</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'news_home' %}"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-newspaper"></i> Новости</li></a>
            <a href=""><li><i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i> Контакты</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'create' %}"><li><button class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Создать</button></li></a>
        </ul>

    </aside>
    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не использовать `float`, как минимум. Есть [flex](https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/), прекрасная штука, и проблемы там не будет – почитайте.

Comment: Я вам оставлял ответ на ваш вопрос (этот же вопрос), как один из вариантов решения, посмотрите - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1429820/Как-сделать-aside-во-всю-высоту-страницы